# If a finite group is generated by $H\le G$ and $g\in G$, then is $G/H = \{g^iH : i\ge 0\}$?

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a finite group, $H\le G$ a subgroup, and $g\in G$ such that $G = \langle H,g\rangle$. Then do the cosets $\{g^iH\}_{i\ge 0}$ give all cosets of $G/H$?

Comment: Many finite groups, including all non-abelian simple groups, are generated by an element of order 3 and an element of order 2. Given such a group $G$, say of order $n$, letting $H$ be the given subgroup of order 3, $G/H$ is usually huge (of cardinal $n/3$) while this gives only 2 cosets. Hence this yields a counterexample as soon as $n>6$. An easier variant consists in observing that every dihedral group is generated by 2 elements of order 2, so any dihedral group of order $\ge 6$ gives rise to a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
Take $G$ to be the symmetric group $S_n$, $H=\big\langle (1\;2)\big\rangle$, and $g=(1\;2\;3\;\ldots\;n)$ for $n\geq 4$.  Then, it is obvious that $G$ is generated by $H$ and $g$.  If $X:=\left\{g^iH\,|\,i=0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\right\}$ is the set of all left cosets of $H$ in $G$, then
$$n!=|G|=|H|\,|X|=2n<n!\,.$$